# configuring run scripts in CMake

Tags: shell, cmake, directory

i have a project which consists of several files like the binary, config files, start stop script, etc.

here's a simplified directory structure

```
/etc/configfile
/etc/xgd/autostart/runfile.Desktop
/usr/local/sbin/startscript
/usr/local/bin/binaryfile
/usr/local/share/project/main.glade
/usr/local/share/project/button.png
```

a runscript will be configured using

```
configure_file(conf/config.h.in ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/config.h)
```

and installed using

```
#copy sbin files
file(GLOB SBINFILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${SBINDIR}/*.sh)

# install scripts
install(FILES ${SBINFILES}
        PERMISSIONS OWNER_READ OWNER_WRITE OWNER_EXECUTE GROUP_READ GROUP_EXECUTE WORLD_READ WORLD_EXECUTE
        DESTINATION ${SBINDIR} 
        COMPONENT binary)
```

and it contains following text

```
#!/bin/bash
# ###############################################
# runscript for my program
# date: 2018/05/21
# ###############################################

export G_MESSAGES_DEBUG=all
export LOGFILE=~/.logfile.log
pushd ${BINDIR}
${BINDIR}/${PROJECTNAME} 1>> $LOGFILE 2>> $LOGFILE
popd
```

well, this works as long as i try to install to /usr/local/share but when I install using

```
make DESTDIR=./dist install
```

there's still /usr/local/bin/binaryfile configured which is logical but not what i want..

Is there any way to add a that destdir to cmake configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DESTDIR` cannot be addeed to CMake *configuration*, because it isn't known on that stage: the variable is known only at *install* step.

Scripts (and executables) provided by the project may be ready for installation with

```
make DESTDIR=<...> install
```

by using **relative paths to other components**:

```
# From /usr/local/sbin/startscript execute /usr/local/bin/binaryfile.
../bin/binaryfile 1>> $LOGFILE 2>> $LOGFILE
```

When it is needed, relative paths can be transformed to absolute using `readlink`:

```
# From /usr/local/sbin/startscript execute /usr/local/bin/binaryfile
# using its absolute path
BINDIR=`readlink -f ../bin/`

pushd ${BINDIR}
${BINDIR}/${PROJECTNAME} 1>> $LOGFILE 2>> $LOGFILE
popd
```